# Can't clone a VM instance from Google Developer Compute Console

Tags: google-compute-engine

I'm trying to clone an instance Centos based and in a load balancing pool. As soon as I click "create" I see the yellow baloon saying "creating instance...." but I don't see the task running in the Activities Windows and the message "creating instance..." freeze for ever.

So I tried creating the instance starting from a snapshot of the original instance but the result is the same. I'm not sure if something happened in the project or the problem is related to the fact the the instance is in a pool of the loadbalancer. Thank you.

This is the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Have you talked to google support? There really isn't any error message for us to diagnose.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: As @Austinh100 said, it's not possible for us to diagnose this issue because there isn't sufficient information provided, and someone might need access to your project or account to investigate further. Please use the _Send feedback_ link at the bottom right of the screen to report this issue to Google.